# Getting resutl of Xpath string() method from XmlNode

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xpath

I've faced the following issue in Python 3.5 on Ubuntu (and it's not reproduced on Windows 10):

getting `.text()` method for the result of `node.select("string(...)")` returns only the first letter of the XPath result.

I've created the following workaround for this case:

`result = ''.join([_.text() for _ in node.select("string(...)")])`

Is this one the only way to get an actual result of the XPath's `string` method, or there is a proper one?

Comment: what library are you using which gives `node.select` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar lxml.etree

Comment: Would be better to provide a [minimal fully working code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the issue . I don't see it having `select()` method